# How to put spacing on flexbox on items in same row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this code and I want two items in the same row with a gap space between them, however this is not working. I want there to be the 12px gap in between the A's and B's. However I don't want to use old techniques like margin/padding.

https://codepen.io/sneaky666/pen/rNxdaOQ

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    AAA
    </div>
    <div>
      BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
 
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  gap:12px;
}
```

I'm following the tutorial from https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-gap-space-with-flexbox

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: *However I don't want to use old techniques like margin/padding.* --> you need to wait until gap is supported with flexbox (your code actually work in the last version of Chrome)

Comment: So there is no flex-gap or anything like that currently?

Comment: It's not well supported yet - https://caniuse.com/?search=gap

Comment: there will be gap for all the layout in the future: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#gaps

Comment: it seem the article you reference gives the solution currently, the one by Cory Ryan. there is no other way to explicitly set a gap width between items on a fluid container.
If you set a width on the container you could set space-between and set widths on the items to equal set width.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a specific number of pixels for the gap, you would need to add a margin in between the items since gap is not currently supported.  Example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first-item">
      AAA
    </div>
    <div>
      BBBBBBBBBBB
    </div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.first-item {
  margin-right: 12px;
}
```

However, if the size of the gap does not matter, you can use the flexbox alignment properties to spread out your divs in the row evenly.  Example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first-item">
      AAA
    </div>
    <div>
      BBBBBBBBBBB
    </div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```